# Can main() have an auto deduced return type?

Tags: c++, c++14

My initial conjecture was that since `main` doesn't [**need**](http://ideone.com/q0QFyT) an explicit return statement (0 will be returned implicitly) :

```
int main() 
{ // This is vaild C++
    cout << "OK\n"; 
}
```

An auto deduced return type could be used without a return statement

```
auto main() 
{ // This is vaild C++
    cout << "OK\n"; 
    // pick up the type from an implicit : 
    // return 0;
}
```

To my surprise though, not even when `return 0` is used, can such a main [**compile**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dad4491d1b397082):

```
auto main ()
{
    std::cout << "OK I'm working" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Why is that ?**

Comment: The result of a compiler using experimental settings doesn't necessarily dictate intent of the standard.  Maybe it is supposed to compile.

Comment: Can the return of `main` by anything *but* int?

Comment: n3337 3.6.1/2 "An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. It shall
have a return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined."

Comment: @MooingDuck Excellent, I'd hope to resolve this from a "language-lawyer" perspective then. I tried all online and offline compilers I can get my hands on, so maybe an answer with solid awareness of the standard so far is needed. I assumed that since auto deduced return types are implemented in some compilers, `main` wouldn't be an exception. Let me edit the Q to avoid misunderstandings